# Wordress Get All Categories using xmlrpc is not working

Tags: xml-rpc

I am trying to get WordPress categories using XML-RPC method and it's working fine on my local as well as sandbox environment but not on production. I am using c# for the same and here is the code.

```
public JsonArray GetCateg(string username, string password){
 IgetCatList categories = (IgetCatList)XmlRpcProxyGen.Create(typeof(IgetCatList));
 XmlRpcClientProtocol clientProtocol = (XmlRpcClientProtocol)categories;
 //clientProtocol.Url = "https://samplewebsite12399.wordpress.com" + "/xmlrpc.php";
 clientProtocol.Url = url + "/xmlrpc.php";
 if (hasServiceUnavailable)
    clientProtocol.UserAgent = "WordPress XML-RPC Client/1.1";
    clientProtocol.KeepAlive = true;
    clientProtocol.Timeout = 42000;
  try
  {

     Category[] wpCategories = categories.GetCategories(1, username, password);
      return wpCategories;
  }
  catch(Exception ex){

  }
}

public interface IgetCatList
{
  [XmlRpcMethod("metaWeblog.getCategories")]
  Category[] GetCategories(int blog_id, string username, string password);
}
```

can anyone help with this issue?

Comment: when you say it doesn't work, can you be specific? E.g. is it 404'ing? It returns partial results? It's not clear what the problem is, just that something went wrong somewhere. It's very possible XMLRPC is not an option for you on the production server, lots of hosts block it for security reasons. Is there a reason you're using XMLRPC rather than a modern API such as the REST API?

Comment: I am getting this error
{"message":"Conflict","stacktrace":" at xmlrpc.XmlRpcClientProtocol.ReadResponse(XmlRpcRequest req, WebResponse webResp, Stream respStm)\r\n at xmlrpc.XmlRpcClientProtocol.Invoke(Object clientObj, MethodInfo mi, Object[] parameters)\r\n at xmlrpc.XmlRpcClientProtocol.Invoke(MethodInfo mi, Object[] Parameters)\r\n at XmlRpcProxy9144647b-28c2-4d11-9ab9-35cd3f53ba20.GetCategories(Int32 blog_id, String username, String password)}

Comment: is that the response you get or is it the error object your local XMLRPC client generated? This would all be a lot easier with a plain request to `/wp-json/wp/v2/categories/1`. If you only have responses from your local XMLRPC library you'll need to share which library you're using for those messages to make sense, otherwise it looks like an arbitrary error message from a compiled language ( C#? Java? )

Comment: I also see that your test site is a wp.com site, sites hosted on WordPress.com can behave differently from normal WordPress, they can have a lot of code that isn't present on other hosts that enables and disables things as they're a bespoke commercial service,